# How to use Struts2 iterator index in non struts tag

Tags: jsp, struts2

I want to generate dynamic `id` for html anchor tag. However `stat.index` will work only if we are using tags defined by Struts.

```
<s:iterator value='environmentList' status="stat" var="env">
    <div>
        <a id="environmentList[%{#stat.index}]" href="#">
            <s:text value="#env.value" />
            <s:hidden id="environmentId[%{#stat.index}]" name="#env.name" />
        </a>
    <div>
</s:iterator>
```

In  the above example, I have a list of object `environmentList` which I am iterating. In anchor tag, I want to generate `id`'s like `environmentList[0]`, `environmentList[1]` etc.. But `[%{#stat.index}]` will work only in Struts tags(like it is working in `s:hidden` tag).

How can I generate dynamic `id`'s in anchor tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got the solution... using `${stat.index}` has worked for me..

```
<s:iterator value='environmentList' status="stat" var="env">
    <li>
        <a id="environmentList${stat.index}" href="#">
            <s:text value="#env.value" />
            <s:hidden id="environmentId[%{#stat.index}]" name="#env.name" />
        </a>
    </li>
</s:iterator>
```